# Problem with Pyscript libary installation

Tags: python, html, pyscript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B7oo.png)

I added the needed google-generativeai but it still dosent work. Can someone help?

Here is the parts of thePy script [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhE7b.png)

Normaly the script should look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deVAC.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, ant an screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, I suspect you're using an older version of PyScript. A complete example using the most recent release as of today (`2024.1.3`) is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.1.3/core.css">
<script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.1.3/core.js"></script>
<py-config>
  packages=['google-generativeai']
</py-config>
<script type="py">
  from pyscript import display
  import google.generativeai as genai
  display(dir(genai))  
</script>
```

This solves the import error, but runs into a later Module Not Found issue, since `gRPC` is not implemented in the Browser. See [this discussion on the Pyodide repo](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/2621).